# Flutter how to show Time Picker as widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to implement time picker as a widget .
I don't need it in modal or dialogue . I need it to be shown in container .any resources or guidlines are appreciated.[image]

Comment: check this repo https://github.com/wuzhendev/flutter-cupertino-date-picker

Comment: I also had the problem and solved it with the package numberpicker: https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get something similar using a `CupertinoTimePicker`.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 4,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Text("Select a time"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                    mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
                    onTimerDurationChanged: (data) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

result:

[image]

Comment: import for retrieving CupertinoTimerPicker is import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';